# Best way to search misspelled words in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, text

I have a table (courses) that contains a description field.
What is the best way to search a phrase containing misspelled words from the description field ?

For example if a user "*mashine laerning*" then it should return all courses which contains words similar to the ones he entered in this case "machine learning".

I’m using PHP in the website.
Thanks!

Comment: This is a typical use case for Levenshtein distance.  You can Google that to learn more.

Comment: Should I create a seperate table that contians each word in the description feild and the course id , then use Levensgtein distance? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: try a seach engine https://lucidar.me/en/web-dev/levenshtein-distance-in-mysql/ or https://sjhannah.com/blog/2014/11/03/using-soundex-and-mysql-full-text-search-for-fuzzy-matching/